# How to reset login screen to default on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, login-screen

I have played around with Ubuntu Tweak and change the login screen.  I have uninstalled Ubuntu Tweak already but my default login screen has not returned.

How can I get reset my login screen to default? I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

My current login screen and loading screen is like:

[image: black background with blue login detail area]

I want it to look like the default login screen for Ubuntu 17.10:

[image: dark purple background with orange login detail area]

The answer to the suggested duplicate helped reset the Ubuntu theme to default, but it does not reset my loading screen and login screen.

How can I can my login screen and loading screen to default ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

You should get something like this:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css        10        auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css   5         manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css        10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The asterisk (*) indicates the current choice, and it should be the `gnome-shell.css` one in your case.

Type the number (in the "*Selection*" column) associated to `ubuntu.css` and press enter.

([Source](https://didrocks.fr/2017/09/11/ubuntu-gnome-shell-in-artful-day-11/))